# How Can I make a Pinterest Grid with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid, pinterest

I want to create a Pinterest grid (items with different height).
I found one, but the problem is that when you load more items, the items change places and reorganize. I can't order the items by date because when I load more items the items that have already been loaded change places.

CSS:

```
ul{
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: auto;
}
li{width: 100%;
margin: 1px;
display: inline-block !important;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;}
```

Note:You can try with the example below, and adding new items with inspect element in the browser.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: did you see this when you searched how to do it?  https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/full/yqrhw/

Comment: If you haven't already you should definitely check out [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's got near full support by all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: @mlegg yes, but if you add more items it will reorder all of them